# Is it possible to boot and run first version of linux (linux-0.11) on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

If yes, would it break my ubuntu or work fine.?

Answer (score 5):

I highly doubt your computer will run properly, and you will most likely break your computer and Linux.

I would NOT run the first Linux kernel on anything, especially given the huge number of security bugs fixed since it was invented, and given the fact you will have no drivers that will work properly with your system (and likely no support for your far-more-modern hardware).

**TL;DR**  It will not work right at all, and will break things.  Doesn't support modern hardware or filesystems or anything. Don't even try it.

Answer (score 3):

No. It will not even boot as it doesn't support modern hardware and file systems.